# Electrical Resistance of molten aluminium oxide

Tags: electrical-engineering, chemical-engineering, metallurgy

I would like to calculate or find the electrical resistance (in ohms) of aluminium oxide at or past its melting point, for the purposes of using it as an electrolyte in a molten state.

My apologies for the broadness I just can't seem to find anything specific to this. Even if you don't have an answer due to the nature, any direction for a conclusion to this question would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should take some time to read up on what resistance and resistivity are.  Resistance depends on material resistivity and the shape of the item in question.    Do you even have info suggesting that AlO2 ionizes when it melts? Because if it doesn't, it's still not going to conduct.

Comment: Thank you very much. I appreciate the direction and what to look for.

Comment: You could google for its specific conductivity (resistance) and then make the calculation for yourself.

Comment: *" electrical resistance (in ohms) of aluminium oxide"*.  Wrong units.  What you want is *resistivity* of the substance itself, which is measured in Ohm-meters.  Once you have a fixed geometry, like a particular length with a particular cross-section area, you can express the *resistance* of that object in Ohms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/231422619_The_Electrical_Conductivity_of_Liquid_Al2O3_Molten_Corundum_and_Ruby) you can find the resistivity of the molten $Al_2 O_3$ at $2400 {}^o C$: $384 ± 5\% \Omega m$. I've found this link with lesser than 10 seconds of googling.

Its melting point is only $2072 {}^o C$ ([source](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aluminiumoxid)). Its resistivity is probably smaller as the referred data. Checking this isn't very simple, because you can't easily extrapolate from the available experimental data (parameters such this tends to varies greatly around the phase shifts).

In your actual case, it depends also on its shape. For a correct calculation, you could make a numerical simulation depending on its temperature distribution. But, as a fist rule, you can relative easily estimate it by simplifying the calculation to a constant-temperature tube.

Comment: Wow, for you 10 seconds and I have been looking for 2 days thank you. This was really helpful. This place is incredible, people like you make it that way.

Comment: Thanks :-) If an answer solves your problem, you can accept it by clicking the pipe icon on the left. It rewards me, and marks the problem as solved.

Comment: I don't know what you found, but resistivity is measured in Ohm-meters, not Ohms/meter.  A value expressed in Ohms/meter makes no sense and is highly suspect along with its source.  This is no answer at all.

Comment: @OlinLathrop It seems to me a trustable research site. It seems they have some latexification problem, and I copy-pasted it. I fixed the post. The numerical value, compared to the values [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_resistivity_and_conductivity#Resistivity_and_conductivity_of_various_materials) looks to me okay.

Comment: OK, downvote removed.